# C Program - Build an index file from another file

Tags: c, binary, indexing

I have a .bin file that contains records in CSV format what I want to do is assign each record in the bin file a sequence number.  So the first record in the bin file would be assigned 0 and so on.  These will be placed into a bianry index file such as (username, seq #).

If I have the bin file already created with records in it, how do I go through the bin file and index each record?  Thanks for any help!

Comment: Could you please explain what a .bin file is for you? There are several possibilites: http://www.fileinfo.com/extension/bin

Comment: The bin file is just includes records in CSV format.  For example, <username, lastname,firstname, numof wins,losses,ties>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would read lines from file A, and write lines to file B. Keep a count of each line you read and use that to generate the sequence number column when writing to file B.

To be honest, I would probably use Excel or a spreadsheet app if the file is already in CSV format